# Conditional Probability of choosing an ace twice in 13 cards

Tags: probability

A 52 card deck is shuffled. You are given 13 cards.

1. If you have one ace, what is the probability that you get another ace?
2. If you have the ace of spades, what is the probability that you get another ace?

I know that these are conditional probability problems, but I'm not sure how to approach them. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: In both cases (1. and 2.) three aces and 39 cards (aces and non-aces) are remaining in the card deck.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that these are conditional probability problems, but I'm not sure how to approach them.

Since that is what they are, you simply use the very definition of conditional probability. $$\mathsf P(A_2\mid A_1)= \dfrac{\mathsf P(A_1\cap A_2)}{\mathsf P(A_1)}$$

In both cases you are required to identify what are the events $A_1$ and $A_1\cap A_2$, then evaluate their probabilities.

> > 1. If you have one ace, what is the probability that you get another ace?

---

> Here, clearly, $A_1$ is the probability for obtaining *at least* one ace among the draw, while $A_1\cap A_2$ is the probability for obtaining *at least* two aces among the draw.

---

> > 2. If you have the ace of spades, what is the probability that you get another ace?

---

> Here, just as obviously, $A_1$ is the probability for obtaining *a particular ace* among the draw, while $A_1\cap A_2$ is the probability for obtaining *that* ace and *at least* one other ace.

The rest is left as an exercise for the student.